# Mailing rule for outlook todo list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter, to-do

## The situation

I have recently set up a few rules in outlook. However, I got stuck when trying to find a way to get items in my todo list automatically when I send mails.

I am doing this because I want to organize all my tasks in 1 place, and 'waiting/following up' is also a common task.

## What have I tried

I tried basically all rules that seemed remotely relevant. I believe that I managed to create a task, but it did not show up on my todo list. Searching online I did not manage to find anything helpfull either.

My workaround now is to use a rule that places a copy the relevant messages (based on a keyword that occurs in the mail) in a special folder. Afterwards I flag them manually, and then they appear in my todo list. However, I don't like this solution because of the manual intervention that is required.

## The question

#### How can I automatically create an item in the todo list when I send certain emails?

---

If possible, I would prefer a point-and-click solution over a customized VBA macro. A solution that would not need to create multiple instances of the mail would be a plus, but is not required.

Comment: VBA is the way to go, see this question/answer over on SO for a hint/starting point: [Is there any way to add a specific category and flag an email in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734395/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-specific-category-and-flag-an-email-in-vba)

Comment: If there was a "point-and-click solution", you would already be using it. Correct? I agree with techie007, VBA is the way to go.

Comment: Isn't flagging the email doing exactly that? Adding it to the to-do bar?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, I think so, but I have been unable to find a way to create flags automatically when sending outgoing mails that show up in the todo bar.